# Github logged in user's public activities

Tags: github

The Github UI/UX has changed entirely just recently. In the old UI of github, you can view your public activities when logged in but in the new UI, I don't seem to find a link where I can click to view my public activities.
But when I am following someone, I can view their public activities (that is fine).

Is there a way in which I can view my public activities (my forks, starred repos, commits etc...) like in the old UI when I am logged in?
Or has Github removed this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have the Overview section now, with dates.
For instance:

https://github.com/VonC?tab=overview&from=2015-12-01&to=2015-12-31

(replace `VonC` by your GitHub account)

And you need to click on "Show more activity" to see the list.

You still can list the activity events your own user account through the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/).
But regarding the website, Overview is the new Activity feed.

Comment: Ok @VonC, that makes sense. Wow, the new Github UI has really changed things. :)

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, I'm using this open-source tool for that:

Source code: https://github.com/caseyscarborough/github-activity
Public instance: http://caseyscarborough.com/github-activity/

Fun fact, 5 years after your problem with Github UI, Github Corp. decided [to remove the Activity Feed](https://github.community/t/how-to-roll-to-previous-recent-activity-theme/185688/6) from their interface..