# How to see a user's recent activity with the new GitHub website?

Tags: github

Previously, GitHub had a site layout where you could go to a user's profile, e.g. https://github.com/someuser, and then click on an 'Public activity' tab in the top right. This would send you to a URL of the form https://github.com/someuser?tab=activity to see their recent activity.

However, GitHub has recently revamped their UI as of [GitHub Universe 2016](https://github.com/blog/2259-mission-report-github-universe). After this change, it looks like user's profile no longer includes a 'Public activity' tab. Even appending `?tab=activity` to the URL manually does nothing. However, the relevant data is still being returned by GitHub's API, for example https://api.github.com/users/jamesqo/events.

Is still there a way to view a user's recent activity after this change? Thanks.

Comment: I think they reformatted it under the "Contribution activity" of the main "Overview" tab, though it seems like it doesn't show as much information as it used to.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/39626016/6309

Answer (score 0):

The URL is now https://github.com/someuser?tab=overview, and its presentation just changed (August 2018)

See "[Profile activity overview](https://blog.github.com/changelog/2018-08-24-profile-activity-overview/)":

> A new beta section is available on your GitHub Profile: the “Activity Overview”.
>
> The “Activity Overview” provides a summary and graphical representation of your contributions to GitHub over time. It’s a fun new way of exploring your contributions and showing them off to others.
>   **Additionally, you can filter your contributions by organization**.
>
> You can enable the “Activity Overview” in the Contribution Settings menu above your contribution calendar.

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/3477155/44541415-d9611d80-a6d7-11e8-9f14-54883cad02f1.gif]